# Selenium Python - Find elements by class name is not working when new elements are loaded

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm writing a Python program to access a website and click buttons that have the same class name.

Conditions:

1. There are 6 buttons provided per one time.
2. When a button is clicked, it disappears.
3. After 6 buttons are clicked, only the section contains the 6 buttons refreshes and the new 6 buttons appear. (then loop like this for a certain amount of times)

The problem is that I can get it to click only the 6 buttons that appear for the first time. After a section contains the buttons refreshes, ***find_elements_by_class_name*** cannot find the new 6 buttons.

**Question: Is there a way to get *find_elements_by_class_name* or any alternatives to find the new 6 buttons every time the section refreshes?**

Thank you so much in advance for your help. Highly appreciate!

Here is a part of my code.

```
webdriver_path = '/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=webdriver_path)

driver.get('https://xxxxx.xxx/')
click_n = 1
While True:
  all_clicks = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('button_me')
  all_clicks[click_n].click()
  print('Click SUCESSFUL')
  click_n +=1
  # if already 6 clicks wait for refresh
  if click_n = 6:
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     click_n -= 6
     continue
  else:
     # Wait till click success notice appear
     NoticeNCon = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Hint"]/div/b[contains(text(),"success")]')))
```

Comment: Please share html for first round and second round of buttons. Do you get an error?

Comment: **1.** What happens afterwards? Which error/exception do you get?

**2.** I don't think you're clicking the first 6 buttons, because you have an array and start clicking from 1, not 0. You need to set the initial value to 0 and set the condition for 5 and extract 5

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Hi all, 

I get this error when the number of clicks reaches 6. 

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

However, I am now able to solve the problem by forcing the whole page to refresh before reaching 6.

Thank you all very much, highly appreciated!